# Data tasks outside ViewController

Tags: swift, urlsession

I'm gonna start with I'm currently learning swift + iOS so I'm by no means an experienced developer or one for that matter.

My goal is to separate any network calls that are currently done in my view controller to a dedicated class outside of it.

In this view controller i have a IBAction with the following code inside of it:

```
let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
let session = URLSession(configuration: config)

session.dataTask(with: loginRequest) {
    (data, response, error) in
    guard let _ = response, let data = data else {return}

    do {
        let apiData = try NetworkManager.shared.decoder.decode(ApiData.self, from: data)
        let token = apiData.data?.token
        let saveToken: Bool = KeychainWrapper.standard.set(token!, forKey: "token")
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.showOrHideActivityIndicator(showOrHide: false)
            self.showHomeScreen()
        }
    } catch let decodeError as NSError {
        print("Decoder error: \(decodeError.localizedDescription)\n")
        return
    }
}.resume()
```

What I want, or I think I want to achieve is something like this:

`let apiData = "somehow get it from outside"`

Then when apiData has info stored in it, execute this next bit of code:

```
let token = apiData.data?.token
let saveToken: Bool = KeychainWrapper.standard.set(token!, forKey: "token")
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.showOrHideActivityIndicator(showOrHide: false)
    self.showHomeScreen()
}
```

How would I achieve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
class API {

  static func userLoginWith(email:String,password:String,completion:@escaping(_ token:String?) -> ()) {

        let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        let session = URLSession(configuration: config)

        session.dataTask(with: loginRequest) {
            (data, response, error) in
            guard let _ = response, let data = data else { completion(nil) ; return }

            do {
                let apiData = try NetworkManager.shared.decoder.decode(ApiData.self, from: data)
                completion(apiData.data?.token) 
            } catch {
                print("Decoder error: ",error")
                completion(nil)
            }
        }.resume()
  }        

}
```

---

Inside the VC

```
API.userLoginWith(email:<##>,password:<##>) { (token) in  

    if let token = token { 
      let saveToken: Bool = KeychainWrapper.standard.set(token!, forKey: "token")
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.showOrHideActivityIndicator(showOrHide: false)
        self.showHomeScreen()
     } 
   } 
}
```

Comment: This answer is great, forgot about escaping closures! Will use this technique in the future, thank you!